# Get string between string without including the matched string in Regex

Tags: php, html, regex

If I want to extract ABC from

```
<td>ABC</td>
```

and

```
<td id="id">ABC</td>
```

using the same regex, how can I do this?

```
<td[\s\S]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/td>
```

This fits the situation, but I want to exclude the matching td tags at the start and end.

Comment: What kind of regex are you using?

Comment: Why not use an HTML parser? I have seen lots of catastrophic backtracking issues even with simplest regexps that tried to parse huge HTML pages.

Comment: @stribizhev HTML parser would be ideal. Can you provide with a sample that fits this situation?

Comment: @Mark im using in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:** Capturing group

```
<td[\s\S]*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/td>
```

Enclose the part of the regex in parentheses that you are interested in and then reference this [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (using `$1` or `\1` for the back reference depending on the regex flavour). **EDIT:** Use `\1` for [PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php).

**Method 2:** Lookbehind / lookahead

***EDIT:*** Modified below to use `\K` instead of variable length lookbehind - credit goes to Jonny 5's good point in the comments.

```
<td\b[^>]*>\K.*?(?=</td>)
```

The tags are then searched for but not included in the match. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) for better explanations than I can give.

Comment: Variable length lookbehind won't work with pcre, but [\K](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) can be used [like this](https://regex101.com/r/uM9sS8/2).

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a regex to parse data out of a valid HTML file/fragment. You can get `td` tag contents using a `DOMDocument` with `DOMXPath`:

```
$html = "<<YOUR_HTML_STRING>>";
$arr = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tds = $xpath->query('//td');

foreach($tds as $td) { 
   array_push($arr, $td->nodeValue);
}

print_r($arr);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Wv60iH)